How to Preview devexpress report using MySql DB in nopcommerece project?
I have NopCommerece Project which we add to it plugins contains DevExpress Reports.
when i try to preview the report it give me an error

but when the project is running it working fine without any error.
although i intstalled MySql package and add its reference manully.

what is the problem??
